# Target _GetRecursiveResolvedSDKReferences does not exist when MSBuild WP8.1 project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, windows-phone-8.1

I try to build Windows Phone 8.1 Apps with command line.

I create a solution and a project WP8.1 with Visual Studio 2013 Pro (File > New > Project...). Then I try to build this newly created project with this command line :

```
msbuild App1.csproj
```

it failed with this error :

```
"C:\...\App1\App1.csproj" 
(cible par défaut) (1) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.WindowsPhone.PostImport.targets(28,13): error MSB4057: La cible "_GetRecursiveResolvedSDKReferences" n'existe pas dans le projet. [C:\...\App1\App1.csproj]
```

The MSBuild.exe used is this one : C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe

Here the complete log of the build :

```
C:\...\App1>msbuild App1.csproj
Microsoft (R) Build Engine, version 4.0.30319.36242
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.0]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

La génération a démarré 01/12/2014 11:11:20.
Projet "C:\...\App1\App1.csproj" sur le noud 1 (cibles par défaut).
CoreResGen:
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\resgen.exe" /useSourcePath 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.Devices.Sensors.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.Phone.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.Phone.Interop.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.Phone.Maps.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.Phone.Media.ElementaryStreams.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.Phone.Reactive.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServicesExtensions.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.MediaLibraryExtensions.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\mscorlib.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\mscorlib.extensions.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Collections.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.ComponentModel.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Core.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Data.Linq.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Device.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Globalization.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.IO.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Linq.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Linq.Expressions.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Linq.Queryable.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Net.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Net.Primitives.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Net.Requests.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.ObjectModel.dll"
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Observable.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Reflection.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Reflection.Emit.IlGeneration.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Runtime.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Security.Principal.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.ServiceModel.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.ServiceModel.Http.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.ServiceModel.Security.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Text.Encoding.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Threading.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Threading.Tasks.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Windows.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Xml.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Xml.Linq.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Xml.Serialization.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Xml.XDocument.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll" 
/r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Silverlight Kits\8.1\\Windows Metadata\Windows.winmd" 
/compile Resources\AppResources.resx,obj\Debug\App1.Resources.AppResources.resources
Traitement du fichier de ressources "Resources\AppResources.resx" dans "obj\Debug\App1.Resources.AppResources.resources".

GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
La cible est ignorée "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute", car tous les fichiers de sortie sont à jour par rapport aux fichiers d'entrée.
CoreCompile:
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE;SILVERLIGHT;WINDOWS_PHONE 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.Devices.Sensors.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.Phone.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.Phone.Interop.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.Phone.Maps.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.Phone.Media.ElementaryStreams.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.Phone.Reactive.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServicesExtensions.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.MediaLibraryExtensions.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\mscorlib.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\mscorlib.extensions.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Collections.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.ComponentModel.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Core.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Data.Linq.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Device.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Globalization.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.IO.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Linq.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Linq.Expressions.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Linq.Queryable.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Net.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Net.Primitives.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Net.Requests.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.ObjectModel.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Observable.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Reflection.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Reflection.Emit.IlGeneration.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Runtime.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Security.Principal.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.ServiceModel.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.ServiceModel.Http.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.ServiceModel.Security.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Text.Encoding.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Threading.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Threading.Tasks.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files(x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Windows.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Xml.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Xml.Linq.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files(x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Xml.Serialization.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Xml.XDocument.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Silverlight Kits\8.1\\Windows Metadata\Windows.winmd" 
/debug+ /debug:full /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\App1.dll 
/resource:obj\Debug\App1.g.resources 
/resource:obj\Debug\App1.Resources.AppResources.resources 
/target:library 
/utf8output App.xaml.cs LocalizedStrings.cs MainPage.xaml.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs Resources\AppResources.Designer.cs "C:\...\App1\obj\Debug\App.g.cs" "C:\...\App1\obj\Debug\MainPage.g.cs" "C:\...\AppData\Local\Temp\WindowsPhone,Version=v8.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs"

_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory:
  Copie du fichier de "C:\...\App1\Assets\ApplicationIcon.png" vers "Bin\Debug\Assets\ApplicationIcon.png".
  Copie du fichier de "C:\...\App1\Assets\Tiles\FlipCycleTileLarge.png" vers "Bin\Debug\Assets\Tiles\FlipCycleTileLarge.png".
  Copie du fichier de "C:\...\App1\Assets\Tiles\FlipCycleTileMedium.png" vers "Bin\Debug\Assets\Tiles\FlipCycleTileMedium.png".
  Copie du fichier de "C:\...\App1\Assets\Tiles\FlipCycleTileSmall.png" vers "Bin\Debug\Assets\Tiles\FlipCycleTileSmall.png".
  Copie du fichier de "C:\...\App1\Assets\Tiles\IconicTileMediumLarge.png" vers "Bin\Debug\Assets\Tiles\IconicTileMediumLarge.png".
  Copie du fichier de "C:\...\App1\Assets\Tiles\IconicTileSmall.png" vers "Bin\Debug\Assets\Tiles\IconicTileSmall.png".

CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
  Copie du fichier de "obj\Debug\App1.dll" vers "Bin\Debug\App1.dll".
  App1 -> C:\...\App1\Bi
  n\Debug\App1.dll
  Copie du fichier de "obj\Debug\App1.pdb" vers "Bin\Debug\App1.pdb".

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.WindowsPhone.PostImport.targets(28,13): error MSB4057: La cible "_GetRecursiveResolvedSDKReferences" n'existe pas dans le projet. [C:\...\App1\App1.csproj]

Génération du projet "C:\...\App1\App1.csproj" terminée (cibles par défaut) -- ÉCHEC.


ÉCHEC de la build.

"C:\...\App1\App1.csproj
" (cible par défaut) (1) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.WindowsPhone.PostImport.targets(28,13): error MSB4057: La cible "_GetRecursiveResolvedSDKReferences" n'existe pas dans le projet. [C:\...\App1\App1.csproj]

    0 Avertissement(s)
    1 Erreur(s)

Temps écoulé 00:00:02.10
```

Have you an idea how to resolve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, in VS2013 and WP8.1 projects, you can't directly use msbuild, you need to init some vars. All this job can be doing with an existing batch in VS2013 folder :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat
```

After this batch is executed, just do a simple msbuild youProjectFile.csproj and it is fix.

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
msbuild App1.csproj
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today with a WP8 solution that was upgraded to the WP81. The upgraded solution built OK in VS2013 targeting the WP81 SDK, but failed in a TFS CI build and when using MSBUILD from the command prompt running on my development PC

The fix that appears to have worked was to add the following target into the failing .csproj file

I placed this at the end of file, just before the closing

Comment: @Richard--your fix doesn't appear in this answer. Can you edit to include that again?

Comment: Been a while since I wrote this, but checking back in source control it seems I added the code I have placed in the extra answer below

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the version of `msbuild.exe` You are using an old version located in `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`The last version is available in this directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer did not include the code, I think this was what I meant to include

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'LiveWindows|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>bin\LiveWindows\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;LIVE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <NoStdLib>true</NoStdLib>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'LiveWindows|ARM'">
    <OutputPath>bin\ARM\LiveWindows\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;LIVE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <NoStdLib>true</NoStdLib>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>ARM</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'LiveWindows|x64'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\LiveWindows\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>CODE_ANALYSIS;CODE_ANALYSIS;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;LIVE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <NoStdLib>true</NoStdLib>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'LiveWindows|x86'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\LiveWindows\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;LIVE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <NoStdLib>true</NoStdLib>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: You should edit your previous answer to include this content instead of creating a new answer.